# Uber Api Unauthorized access

Tags: authorization, uber-api

I am working on integrating Uber api's. I am not able to make ride request using access token, it say '**Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided**'

I am able to get profile and history information but whenever I make ride request I get a response '**Unauthorized**'

In uber developer account I am not able to enable request scope and this could be the reason for above mentioned error.

is this the issue with uber developer console and if not what could be the reason and how to resolve it.

[Screen shot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3llPQ.png)

thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Are you using the Production or the [Sandbox](https://developer.uber.com/docs/sandbox) Uber API to send the ride request?

  Uber API sandbox URL =  https://api.uber.com/v1
  Uber API production URL = https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1

  For production you need to send your request for review inside [Uber Developers Dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard) by pressing the "REQUEST FULL ACCESS" button besides the "request" scope in the Authorizations tab.
- If you are using the Sandbox API and you get 401 unauthorized HTTP response status code, then this means that the Bearer token you are sending to the [POST /v1/requests](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-requests) endpoint has not been granted the "request" scope.

  - Make sure that the access token has been granted the "request" scope, in the [step 1 of the OAuth2 authentication flow](https://developer.uber.com/docs/authentication#section-step-one-authorize)
  - Make sure that you are sending a Bearer token and not the server token for the ride request.
    (The ride request should contain the "Authorization: Bearer token_here"
    header, NOT "Authorization: Token token_here")
  - Make sure that the Bearer token is still valid (hasn't expired, or hasn't been invalidated by another login of the same Uber user)
  - Make sure that you are sending the mandatory parameters: i.e. start_latitude/start_longitude or start_place_id with your request

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35580167/313113)

Comment: yes I am using Sandbox Uber API and I followed the same produce as you mentioned but still I get the same 401 unauthorized response

Comment: After following your answer, I noticed that access token has not been granted with "request" token. It has been granted general scopes but not any of privileged scopes.  As I mentioned in my question I am not able to enable privileged scopes from developer console ( please refer the image link in my question).

Comment: Yes I understand now. Need to find out the cause.  Thank you very much for your information.

Answer (score 0):

The request scope is whitelist only which means you need to submit your app for review by our team before we issue that scope to your application. With that said, if you attempt to go through the OAuth flow for your application using the Uber account associated with the application in the developer platform you'll be able to request the "request" scope.

Best,
   Richie

Comment: Our application is not ready for production. We are still in development

Comment: Then you can test the request scope using the developer accounts associated with the application

Comment: @RichardArtoul I am trying to request a ride using my own account (developer associated with the app). I still get a response saying unauthorized. Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you obtaining the access token?